# C# Settings Problems, Can't convert type string

Tags: c#

New to C# here, and I'm trying to store a string in a Setting.

Heres what I have:

```
string test = "Setting to save!";    
Properties.Settings.Default.testSetting = test;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

However I get this error:

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection'

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Properties.Settings.Default.testSetting` is most likely a `StringCollection`

Check the IDE for settings and see if you chose the wrong type.